# Weird behavior of `search-forward-regexp` influenced by buffer mode change

Tags: regular-expressions, search, grep, info

Action 1:  evaluate the lisp expression: `(search-forward-regexp "\\s'")`
in a buffer in `lisp-interaction-mode` containing the text:

> The pandemic market was cooling, but homes in north Seattle were still
> going for over asking price. 'A few homes they were interested in
> received multiple offers,' she said, 'and sold for 10 to 15 percent
> over list price.'

Result 1: the comma after "cooling" will be found.

---

Action 2:  evaluate the exact same expression above in another buffer, containing the exact same text, except that this time the bufer is in  `text-mode`.

Result 2: nothing will be found and a `search-failed` error is issued.

---

The question is thus: what justifies this weird behavior?

I cannot understand why a buffer's mode would affect the
behavior of `search-forward-regexp`.  It totally
blows my mind that the "comma" is found in the first case.
Regarding the second case, things are still incomprehensible since
`"\\s"` is described in the manual as

> Match whitespace, it is a synonym for ‘[[:space:]]’

so the second
search should match the space before "A few homes" followed by
the single quote.

Could I possibly be interpreting things in the wrong way?

Comment: Which manual are you looking at?  Please direct us to the phrase "Match whitespace, it is a synonym for ‘[[:space:]]’", because that isn't true.

Comment: It turns out that was a quote from the GNU `grep` manual, which explains the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which manual you're looking at, but `\\s` is not a synonym for `[[:space:]]`.

In the double-quoted read syntax for strings, `"\\s'"` is the regexp `\s'` which means this:

```
‘\sCODE’
     matches any character whose syntax is CODE.  Here CODE is a
     character that represents a syntax code: thus, ‘w’ for word
     constituent, ‘-’ for whitespace, ‘(’ for open parenthesis, etc.  To
     represent whitespace syntax, use either ‘-’ or a space character.
     *Note Syntax Class Table::, for a list of syntax codes and the
     characters that stand for them.
```

Syntax tables are buffer-local and therefore different modes may indeed set different syntax for a given character.

`\s'` matches any character which is an "expression prefix":

```
Expression prefixes: ‘'’
     Characters used for syntactic operators that are considered as part
     of an expression if they appear next to one.  In Lisp modes, these
     characters include the apostrophe, ‘'’ (used for quoting), the
     comma, ‘,’ (used in macros), and ‘#’ (used in the read syntax for
     certain data types).
```

Refer to:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Regexp Backslash`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Syntax Class Table`

Comment: OK, so I am indeed interpreting things in the wrong way.  The
info node `(grep)The Backslash Character and Special Expressions`
states that ‘\s’ matches whitespace and I erroneously understood
that I should double the backslash as it is usually required by
the read syntax for strings.  Now I see that there is a
difference between *"the escaped character s"* and *"the string
formed by the characters backslash plus s"* and clearly the
manual adopts the previous interpretation.  Thanks very much for
pointing it out!

Comment: You were reading the manual for GNU `grep`, which is a command-line program that is fully independent of Emacs.  The info reader allows you to access manuals for many things besides Emacs.  You need to read the Emacs manuals -- primarily `(elisp)`, the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, or `(emacs)` for end-user documentation.  There are numerous others, but they should all be grouped under an "Emacs" heading in the info directory.

Comment: Note that `M-x elisp-index-search` is often a great entry point.

Comment: And for total clarity: Although both `grep` and Emacs support regular expressions, there's no reason to expect that they (or indeed any other program) use *the same syntax* to represent regexps, nor that they support the same set of regexp features.  Emacs regexps are in fact fairly similar to the default BRE regexps used by grep, but they are definitely not the same; and in general reading the manual for program A in order to learn how to use program B is going to be a mistake.

Comment: Phils, you are right,  besides messing up with the interpretation of  the backlash character I was using the wrong manual.  I am from another area of science, where concepts are pretty much universaly defined, and I erroneously imagined that this principle applies to computer science!